# Objective C Equivalent of PHP's "Variable Variables"

Tags: objective-c

In PHP and in JavaScript you can dynamically use a variable by using another variable as part of its name. I do not want to use an array as part of the solution. Can this be achieved in Objective C? I'd like to do something like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
        if([appRecord.answer(i) length] != 0){
            self.textView.answer(i)ViewSingle.text = appRecord.answer(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231783/create-multiple-variables-based-on-an-int-count/2231839#2231839 

Not saying you'll like the answer, but there it is. Use an array.

Comment: I think the questions are similar but not the same. The answer is the same though, of course.

Comment: How could this question be a duplicate of another question that was asked more than a year after this one? Oh moderators...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Kind of.

1. You can use an array, store your variables in there, and index into it.
2. Like #1, if your objects are actually UI elements and you don't want a whole bunch of `IBOutlets`, then use an `IBOutletCollection` instead.
3. You can use a dictionary, store your variables as values, and look them up by key.
4. You can declare all your variables as `@property`, and then use `[self valueForKey:]` to look them up by name.
5. You can build the name of the ivar as a string, and then use something like [`object_getInstanceVariable()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_getInstanceVariable) to retrieve it's value directly (this is similar to #3, except you don't have to declare it as an `@property`).  This is excessively complicated and is usually a much bigger hammer than you'll actually need.
6. If you're dealing with views, you can assign each view a unique tag and then retrieve it via `[superview viewWithTag:aTag]`.  I do not recommend using this approach.

EDIT:  Note that this only works with instance variables.  This does not work with global/static variables.

Comment: Wow, [self valueForKey:] was exactly what I needed as all of the variables I need were already declared using @property. object_getInstanceVariable may work as well, but I'm not sure yet. You have offered by far the best answer on this topic on the internet.

Comment: @Cirrostratus - glad to help. I would use `object_getInstanceVariable()` as a second or third option.  `valueForKey:` is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can give a tag to the view and use `-viewWithTag:`.