# NSString Formatting - string by string name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a couple of `NSStrings` that hold some simple text. An example:

```
NSString *string1 
*string2 etc
```

I am going to be setting the contents of those strings to a label but at random, my intention was to use the last number in the string name and `arc4random`. So im wondering if there is a method that would essentially be `NSString stringWithStringName = @"string%i", randomInt;`

Is there something that would accomplish this or would it be better to put them into an array and use `objectAtIndex`. Or something much more clever that hadnt occured to me?
Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C Equivalent of PHP's "Variable Variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is put all of the strings into an array:

```
NSArray *stringArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:string1, string2, string3, nil];
```

Then, you can use `arc4random()` to choose a random string from the array:

```
int randomIndex = arc4random()%[stringArray count];
NSString *randomString = [stringArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *result;
result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %d", string1, string2, someInt];
```

Look up String formatting in the docs for more details.