# Set a (different) property based on a value in a variable?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C Equivalent of PHP’s “Variable Variables”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables)

I have a UIButton action, that grabs the button sender

This line gives me the sender tag which I'm using in a switch statement

```
int senderTag = [sender tag];
```

I then have to do...

```
switch (senderTag) {
    case 1:
       brain.selectedPaintColor1 = myColor;
       break;
    case 2:
       brain.selectedPaintColor2 = myColor;
       break;
    case 3:
       brain.selectedPaintColor3 = myColor;
       ...
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is use the tag to set a variable property name like this

```
[brain.selectedPaintColor%i,senderTag] = myColor;
```

Can anyone assist with the syntax to be able to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct translation of what you want

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"selectedPaintColor%i", senderTag];

[brain setValue:myColor forKey:key];
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, since the assignment methods above are really being translated into calls to setter methods, one could build an array of selectors and call a method from the indexed array.  (Not going to slog through the syntax just now though -- selectors always make my head hurt.)

(And, in fact, there's a way to dynamically look up a selector, so you could build the selector name string and look it up, vs pre-constructing an array.)

Answer (score 0):

Combine your properties `selectedPaintColor1` , `selectedPaintColor2` etc. into an `NSMutableArray` and use that as a property. Now the syntax is:

```
[brain.paintColors replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:myColor];
```

Be aware that if your `sender` is of type `id` you will have to cast it into a `(UIView)` first.