# How to reference an objects id with a variable?

Tags: objective-c

This is my code, which occurs 48 times (one for each button in a calendar).

```
calenderButton *a1 = [calenderButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[a1 makeFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 70, 70) number:1 color:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[self.view addSubview:a1];
```

What I want to do is put this in a "for loop", changing the "a1" to "a2", "a3", etc, to cut down on the amount of code.  I figure I can cut it down to 6 "for loops".

How do I get the "a1"s to be a variable that I can then reference in not only the code above but in the "for loop"?  (the for loop would be something like this:)

```
for(int i = 0, j=75; i < 7; i++, j+=75);
```

I know I have to concatenate the "a" with the integer "i", but how do I place that in the message?

Comment: why are you trying to do this? How is it more beneficial than having an array(s) of the objects?

Comment: There's also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2283374/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7758757/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7601937/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8090590/, and others linked from those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your buttons into an array, like this:

Declare an instance variable `NSMutableArray *allButtons` in your header, then...

```
allButtons = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0, j=75; i < 7; i++, j+=75) {
    calenderButton *cb= [calenderButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    // Configure the button here...
    // use values of i and j to call CGRectMake, or as you see fit
    [allButtons addObject:cb];
}
```

Now all your buttons are in an array. You can access them by index or in any other way that you may need, e.g. with a fast enumeration loop.

Comment: Thank you... works like a champ!

Answer (score 3):

Your code will create 48 **different** buttons even if you use the same (local) variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++){
    calenderButton *a1 = [calenderButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [a1 makeFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 70, 70) number:1 color:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:a1];
}
```

If you want to keep a reference to the buttons, you can store them in an array:

```
self.buttons = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++){
    calenderButton *a1 = [calenderButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [a1 makeFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 70, 70) number:1 color:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:a1];
    [self.buttons addObject:a1];
}
```

And access them later like this:

```
calenderButton *button = [self.buttons objectAtIndex:7]; // Or any other index
```

---

Note, you can use the loop you mentioned:

```
for(int i = 0, j=75; i < 7; i++, j+=75)
```

But I am not sure this will produce 48 buttons.

Comment: sch:  how does it add 48 DIFFERENT buttons?  each has to have a unique identifier so I can reference it... in this case, they are all called "a1", right?

Comment: @spokane-dude: actually, no. This adds 48 different buttons because you create 48 different buttons. The name isn't unique in the global scope, only in the scope of the loop. To reference a button you would use `[[self buttons] objectAtIndex:7];` This would essentially be the a7 button you are looking for, but it wouldn't be available via the `a7` pointer

Comment: That's ok that I can't reference via a7 pointer... I need to have the ability to add and remove objects (labels and symbols) from any of the generated buttons...

Comment: As @ColdLogic said, you can reference them using their index in the array.

Comment: An extra tip: when dealing with a bunch of similar views (like your calendar setup), it's often useful to group them in a containing view and give each a unique integer tag -- then you can refer to them with `viewWithTag:`.