# Set variable name depending on other variable

Tags: variables, cocos2d-iphone, c-preprocessor

me need make settings language

I've got:

```
#define kMenuSettingsHeaderrus @"Настройки"
#define kMenuSettingsHeadereng @"Settings"
```

and I want use this global variables to set string to label depending on

```
_language= [[SettingsManager sharedSettingsManager] getLanguage];

_language can be @"rus" or @"eng"

CCLabelTTF *settingsLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"kMenuSettingsHeader%@",_language] fontName:kLabelFontNameTTF fontSize:kMenuHeaderFontSize];
```

can you help me, in php i do this like $$

one example from php:

```
$a = "hello";
$$a = "world"; => $hello="world"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you were doing would have given kMenuSettingsHeadereng or kMenuSettingsHeaderrus as result because instead of macros they will be treated as strings... So Use this

```
#define kMenuSettingsHeaderrus @"Настройки"
#define kMenuSettingsHeadereng @"Settings"


_language= [[SettingsManager sharedSettingsManager] getLanguage];

CCLabelTTF *settingsLabel;
 if ([_langueage isEqualToString:@"rus"])
{
settingsLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:kMenuSettingsHeaderrus fontName:kLabelFontNameTTF fontSize:kMenuHeaderFontSize];
}
else if ([_langueage isEqualToString:@"eng"])
{
settingsLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:kMenuSettingsHeadereng fontName:kLabelFontNameTTF fontSize:kMenuHeaderFontSize];
}
```

Check for the syntax... I don't have X-code to check for that... Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: ok, I know this way... but i want something like stringWithFormat:@"kMenuSettingsHeader%@",_language] more shortly

Comment: Actually what you are doing is convert this into string rather than macro...
You code is not settingsLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:kMenuSettingsHeaderrus fontName:kLabelFontNameTTF fontSize:kMenuHeaderFontSize];

Its settingsLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"kMenuSettingsHeaderrus" fontName:kLabelFontNameTTF fontSize:kMenuHeaderFontSize];

Now think yourself.. Are they equal?

Comment: I'm really understand this and it lead me to the question: How can i concatenate the name of variable from name of the first variable and value of the other variable

Comment: I added the example from PHP, to make more clear the meaning my question

Comment: the answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables