# incrementing variable names in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Incrementing variable names

In xcode I want to create 100 images one with the name1,2,3,4 ect. And i can do it all except for the variable names. For these I was wandering is it possible to increment the variables programmatically or whether it must be done manually?

Comment: Why load 100 images into memory if you could simply cache and display... 3 at a time.  What exactly might you be doing?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a bunch of variable names, you can use a dictionary object with the names as keys and the image object as the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to/have to use 100 different variables and avoid an array you could use Key Value Coding in combination with a for loop:

```
NSString *name = @"myVariable";
for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
{
    // get aValue from somewhere...
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", name, i];
    [self setValue:aValue forKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is best achieved with an array.

Similar question here: [Objective C Equivalent of PHP's "Variable Variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Create them in an `NSMutableArray`. Doesn't matter if all of them have the same object name, since they have different locations in the array. Just access them with [arrayName objectAtIndex:index]; Use a for.