# Accessing a variable using string

Tags: objective-c, variables, nsstring, nsarray

I was wondering if one of you could help me with a little problem I am having, if it is possible. I have a few global variables called ChecklistA, ChecklistB, etc. What I want, is if the user selects a table cell called A, that ChecklistA is passed on to the destination controller.

In other words: 
Global variables: NSArrays -> "ChecklistA", "ChecklistB", "ChecklistC", etc. 
Cells: "A", "B", "C", etc 
 
... on click of cell B... 
destinationController.checklist = NSArray named: "ChecklistB"


I hope this is clear, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your table view has this delegate method implemented:

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You get notified whenever a cell is selected(tapped) by the user.

You can implement your delegate method in this way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if( indexPath.row == 0) /// First cell
   {
       _selectedChecklist = ChecklistA;
   }
   else if( indexPath.row == 1) /// Second cell
   {
       _selectedChecklist = ChecklistB;
   }
   else if( indexPath.row == 2) /// Third cell
   {
       _selectedChecklist = ChecklistC;
   }
}
```

for your `prepareForSegue`, simply pass the value to your destination viewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   destinationController.checklist = _selectedChecklist; 
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to implement this method without using else if, etc. Is there anyway to do it the way I described in my question?

Comment: If you declared the variables as property within the class, you can use `[self valueForKey:@"<name of property>"]`, else you can try adding them in an array or dictionary then retrieve them with the index/key accordingly. Similar question has been asked here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables)