# Create NSMutableArray by a NSString value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

How I can create a NSMutableArray (name) dynamically by a NSString value?

```
e.g. NSString *stringName = @"helloArray1";
```

Then create the NSMutableArray with the "helloArray1" dynamically.

```
e.g. NSMutableArray * (--here the stringName / helloArray1---) = [NSMutableArray new];
```

And then the NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"%@", (--here the stringName / helloArray1---) );
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You mean you'd like to create a _variable_ with a certain name dynamically? That's not possible; but if you want to fill an existing _instance variable_ with a certain name instead, there is a way to do that.

Comment: One possible way would be a dictionary where the array would be the value for `stringName` key...

Comment: @DarkDust: Have you code example to fill an existing instance variable with a certain name?

Comment: @Alladinian: Have you code example?

Comment: @Daniela: Search for "Key-Value Coding", an important concept in Objective-C: you can usually do `[self setValue:someObject forKey:@"instanceVariableName"]`.

Comment: @DarkDust: Thx but Key-Value Coding doesn't solve my problem. Unfortunately I think it is your first sentence (...not possible...).

Comment: Instead of describing _how_ you want to solve your problem, it might help if you actually described _what_ you're trying to do. What's the "big picture" you're trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible.

Better is set dynamically all into object. For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
    [variables setObject:temp forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"value_%d", i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", [variables objectForKey:@"value_1"]);
```