# want to use a for loop to set property on multiple objects

Tags: objective-c, object, for-loop

Here is a rookie question.  I want to use a for loop to set the visibility on several buttons.  Here is what i wanted to do:

```
for (int y = 0; y < numberOfPeople; y++) {
    button[y].hidden = true;
}
```

where I have 5 buttons named:  button1, button2, button3, button4, button5  and number of people is the variable I am sending.

Comment: possible duplicate of [create multiple variables based on an int count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231783/create-multiple-variables-based-on-an-int-count)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using an array:

```
NSButton *buttons[5];
```

You can either define your instance variable this way, or you can do this:

```
NSButton *buttons[5] = { button1, button2, button3, button4, button5 };
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    button[i].hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I knew it would be super easy.  This is PERFECT!  Love it.  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray* buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, nil];
for (id aButton in buttons)
{
    aButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

Has the advantage that the loop does not need to know how many buttons it has got.