# Syntax help - Variable as object name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create multiple variables based on an int count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231783/create-multiple-variables-based-on-an-int-count)
>   [Objective C Equivalent of PHP's “Variable Variables”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables)

How would I create and reference an object using a variable as it's name?

Example -

```
    for (int i=1; i<7; i++) {
       CGRect ("myRectNum & i") = myImageView.bounds; 
    }

 ("myRectNum & 5").height  etc ..
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [create multiple variables based on an int count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231783/create-multiple-variables-based-on-an-int-count) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/, among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything like this in the Objective-C language, and in general it's not going to be a very practical way of referring to data (what if you typo a string? the compiler won't be able to catch it). I won't get into second-guessing what you actually want to do (that would depend on the goal of this part of your application), but you can use an `NSMutableDictionary` to get a similar effect:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myRectNum & %d", i];
    NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:myImageView.bounds];
    [dict setObject:value forKey:key];
}
```

Then to fetch the values back out again:

```
NSValue *value = [dict objectForKey:@"myRectNum & 5"];
CGRect bounds = [value CGRectValue];
NSLog(@"height = %f", bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using this method for simple variables but is it possible to store a path?  myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

Comment: Yes, you can store a CGPathRef in a dictionary. If you are using ARC you will need to look at the __bridge, etc. qualifiers.