# Call method with keyValueCoding (setValue:forKeyPath:)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm stuck with a little problem:

```
Player *player1;
Player *player2;
Player *player3;
Player *player4;
```

Inside `Player` class, I have a variable called, `score`. If I need to change all players score, I use this function:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    [self setValue:@"10,000" forKeyPath: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"player%i.score.text", i]];
}
```

Also in the `Player` class, I have a method called `changeScorePosition`. I would like to call this method for all "Players" in the game. How do I do this?

Comment: I didn't understand, what is your actual requiement, can you please explain ?

Comment: Thanks for response. I edit the question, to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

Is player1 a global variable?

Instead, try creating an object to manage all players.  This object could then easily iterate through all the players and update their score.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the players in an array and then call the correct player based on index using i (although it would need to start at 0).

```
NSArray *players = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: player1, player2, player3, player4, nil];


for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  Player *currentPlayer = (Player *)[players objectAtIndex:i];
  // do whatever with your player here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to create number of player like this,

```
NSMutableArray *playerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    Player *player = [{Player alloc] init];
    [playerArray addObject:player];
    [player release];
}
```

And call the methods like,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    [self setValue:@"10,000" forKeyPath: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"player%i.score.text", i]];
    [[playerArray  objectAtIndex:i-1] changeScorePosition];
}
```

Refer this link: [access objective-c object by string name or variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261380/access-objective-c-object-by-string-name-or-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I change to code some, and found that I can do this:

```
[[self valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"player%i", i]] performSelector:@selector(playerDeclined)];
```