# variable inside variable name

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have a `int` variable called `pageIndicator`.

I would like to include it inside another variable so it will save me some lines of code.

This is what I have:

```
Products *productPage0 = [productArray objectAtIndex:0];
Products *productPage1 = [productArray objectAtIndex:1];
Products *productPage2 = [productArray objectAtIndex:2];
Products *productPage3 = [productArray objectAtIndex:3];
```

And this is what I want:

```
Products *productPage(@"%d", pageIndicator) = [productArray objectAtIndex:pageIndicator];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What's this syntax on the last code line?

Comment: Why can't you use `[productArray objectAtIndex: index]`?

Comment: Your design has a major flaw if you need to use dynamic variable names. Tell why do you think you need this, then we can tell you what is the problem with your design/thinking.

Comment: If its an 'int' you could just make a C array and get the int by using 'productPage[n]'.  With 'n' being your indicator.

Comment: I have a store inside my app, with four different subviews under the same `uiscrollview`. each of them need labels and imageviews get text, image, and some other information. Later I wish to use the pageIndicator integer with ZooZ shopping cart framework to check on what subview the "add to cart" is being used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C Equivalent of PHP's "Variable Variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables) or [Variable as object name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940809/syntax-help-variable-as-object-name)

Answer (score 1):

How'bout a preprocessor macro?

```
#define PRODUCT_PAGE(n) products *productPage##n = [productArray objectAtIndex:n]
```

Use it like:

```
PRODUCT_PAGE(0);
PRODUCT_PAGE(1);
```

etc.

(This is extremely bad practice, btw).

Comment: If's interesting. What's the ## syntax for?

Comment: btw, why is a bad practice by using the macro to solve the problem?

Comment: @luyuan because that's not what macros are for. C is in itself a good Turing-complete language in which you should be able to solve problems without tricky metaprogramming.

Comment: @luyuan macros' job is 1. to give some convenience by not having to rewrite redundant pieces of code, in a way similar to functions, 2. to define constants which are not to be exposed in the binary code. 3. etc. -- it can't exactly be defined, you'll see it when you have a bit more experience with C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store your Products object and set the name as the corresponding key.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int i =0; i < productArray.count; i++) {
    [dic setValue:[productArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[@"productPage" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",i] ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the advantage of having 4 similar named variables against just using your `productArray`?

Instead of using `productPageX` you simply could use `[productArray objectAtIndex:X]`.