# Can I do NSVariableFromString like NSClassFromString and NSSelectorFromString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Right so I have noticed that you can do NSClassFromString and NSSelectorFromString.

Is it possible to do something like NSVariableFromString?

Comment: I'm not actually trying to do anything I was just wondering. Could this really be done using the NSSelectorFromString? As when you are getting a variable you are actually calling the getter for it.

Comment: Not all variables have selectors, only properties.

Comment: It wasn't me who voted - but it's hard to think of any real world, useful reason to do what you asked and you haven't provided a use case either...

Comment: @Paul.s OK. I am grateful for the response. +1. The reason I was wondering was because I have just had to use NSSelectorFromString to dynamically change the method it needs to call based on some settings. I don't need it at the moment but I can see myself needing something like it in the near future and I thought I would get the question asked now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax help - Variable as object name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940809/syntax-help-variable-as-object-name)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I disagree these two questions are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objective C runtime has lots of goodies for your consumption.

If you want an iVar, you can call object_getInstanceVariable with a string name.

If you want variables, it's a bit more work, and they have to be globally visible to the linker.  You can use CFBundleGetDataPointerForName for that purpose.

Be sure to read the documentation for restrictions and specific information about runtime information, and the availability of stuff on different platforms.

Comment: `object_getInstanceVariable` "is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode"  any alternatives?

Comment: @alexgray That appears to be new with the latest update.  I can't find any documentation on the change.  However, you can still obtain the `IVar` reference with `class_getInstanceVariable`.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Compiled applications don't contain variable names except when debug info is included and it usually isn't for release applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can get *values* from strings using `NSScanner` but, as [JemeryP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11794322/2998) notes, at runtime variable names have generally been converted to pointers and memory addresses.