# How to declare a variable named after the value of another variable in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax help - Variable as object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940809/syntax-help-variable-as-object-name)

I have a very basic beginner's question in Objective C:

I'd like to declare a variable that is named after the content/value/literal of another variable. How can I do that?

I.e.

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"variableName"];
```

// now create a second variable that is named after the literal in s

```
int *s = 42; // This is what doesn't work. The integer-type variable should be named variableName
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for the answers so far. The reason why I am asking this questions is the following:

I have an array containing values I load from an xml file structured as follows:

`<string>name</string><integer>23</integer><real>3.232</real><real>4.556</real> ... (44 times another real number)<string>nextName</string>...(and so on).`

The file contains the names for MKPolygons, the number of points for each polygon and the latitude and logitude values for each point of the polygon. I managed to load the file and have its content in an array. Now I want to create MKPolygons from this array which are named as the strings in the array.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a hash table. You can use `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSHashTable`.

Here is an example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:anObj forKey:@"foo"];
[dict objectForKey:@"foo"];
[dict removeObjectForKey:@"foo"];
[dict release];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Objective-C, nor in most mainstream languages (save for PHP). What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: lol you are 4 secs faster than me..

Comment: It is very possible with a hashmap, otherwise known as an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it. However, you can create an `NSDictionary` and create a key called `variableName` and a value called `42`. (an `NSNumber`). Then whenever you want to retrieve this value, you can just do `valueForKey`.