# Dynamically construct variable name as in Actionscript

Tags: objective-c, variables, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C Equivalent of PHP’s “Variable Variables”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables)

Today in one of my classes I learned you can access a variable by building its name from a string in Actionscript 3.0, like so:

```
var star1:symbol;
var star2:symbol;
var star3:symbol;
var star4:symbol;

for(i=1; i <= 4; i++)
    [this "star" + i].method = something
```

This gets `star1`, then `star2`, then `star3`, then `star4`, and does some method with them.

Is there a way to do something like this in Objective-C?

Comment: don't you mean this["star"+i].method

Comment: possible duplicate of [ObjC equivalent of PHP's "Variable Variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables), [Create multiple variables based on an int count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231783/create-multiple-variables-based-on-an-int-count/), [Syntax help: variable as object name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940809/syntax-help-variable-as-object-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite as neat, but [key-value coding](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/) does that:

```
[self setValue:something forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"star%u", i]]
```

EDIT: on reflection it's unclear as a non-Actionscript user whether you intend to access properties or call methods.

You'd use `NSSelectorFromString` to convert the name of a method into a selector at runtime, then `[self performSelector:...]` to call the thing if it's the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use an `NSArray`. Then you can do something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, nil];
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    [[array objectAtIndex:i] doMethod];
}
```

Or even easier:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, nil];
for (id obj in array) {
    [obj doMethod];
}
```

Comment: Or even just `@[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]` in the modern world?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can put the variables in an array and achieve the same that way.