# How to Make a Dynamically Named Method Parameter?

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C Equivalent of PHP’s “Variable Variables”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables)

I have created a method in objective C which looks like this:

```
- (void) startBuildingXArray: (NSMutableArray *) arrayName:(int) senderID;
```

BUT, here is the tricky part. The particular arrayName argument depends on what the senderID is. Specifically, each arrayName has a number at the end of it (i.e. array1, array2, etc.) that matches the senderID in this method. Is there a way to dynamically add in an integer to the end of array name as a parameter? Or an entirely different and better way to yield the same result?

In other words, what I want to create is this sort of a situation:

```
- (void) startBuildingXArray: (NSMutableArray *) arrayName+(senderID):(int) senderID;
```

Of course that is not in any way valid code, I'm just trying to demonstrate what I want to happen. Can anyone suggest any sort of solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ObjC equivalent of PHP's "Variable Variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables), [Create multiple variables based on an int count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231783/create-multiple-variables-based-on-an-int-count/), [Syntax help: variable as object name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940809/syntax-help-variable-as-object-name)

Comment: if senderID is an argument then why do you also want it as part of the method name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lucky: Objective-C is a dynamic language, so you can create selectors (method names) at runtime and also add corresponding implementation functions to them. Let's assume you have already implemented these methods (for example, from `startBuildingXArray:arrayName1:` to `...arrayName9:` etc.), and you're looking for a way to call them depending on the integer ID:

```
- (void)callMethodWithParam:(NSMutableArray *)parm ID:(int)ident
{
    // get the selector name and the selector
    char zelektor[128];
    snprintf(zelektor, sizeof(zelektor), "startBuildingXArray:arrayName%d:", ident);
    SEL realSel = sel_getUid(zelektor);

    // Alternatively you can use Foundation as well:
    /*
    NSString *zelektor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"startBuildingXArray:arrayName%d:", ident];
    SEL realSel = NSSelectorFromString(zelektor);
     */

    // Grab a function pointer to the implementation corresponding to the selector
    IMP imp = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], realSel);

    // and call the function pointer just obtained
    imp(self, realSel, parm, ident);
}
```

If you want to mass-create methods with names like this, you can use a similar approach but use the `class_addMethod()` [Objective-C runtime function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW6) instead.

However, this is a hack. I'd rather suggest you use one function and implement its task depending on the integer identifier that is passed in.